# repartition(1) - Makes loading very slow

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher, databricks, azure-databricks

When I load 20 Million records from spark - Databricks into neo4j when I mention repartition (1) While writing into neo4j - It takes a lot of time for loading all the records. If I didnt mention repartition(1) it is failing with database not upto the requested version error. How to overcome this?

DBR specifications: 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

Connector - Libraries:

spark_cdm_connector_assembly_0_19_0.jar, neo4j-contrib:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.11:4.0.1

Neo4j - Single Neo4j Instance

Error:

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.TransientException: Database 'xxx' not up to the requested version: 1879. Latest database version is 1867

Comment: can you post the error message that you receive when you remove `.repartition`, also, how do you write data - what connector is used, etc.